# Why Telegram Bot API Web hook repeated infinitely?

Tags: laravel, telegram

I using laravel and php bot sdk for my bot.
here is the laravel route code :

```
Route::post('268XXXX:XXXXXX/webhook',function(){
Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
Telegram::setWebHook(['url'=>URL::to('/').'/268XXXX:XXXXXX/webhook']);
return response()->json("{}")->setStatusCode(200);
```

});

and help command executed infinitely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Telegram send an update to your server, if your server return any status **except 200**, then Telegram consider that you doesn't notify about the update, so Telegram repeat the update continuously!

Also some times; an error accrues in your code execution and code stopped at the certain line. In these case, you can save & check `update_id` of received update in database, at first lines of your program, so you can ignore such repeated updates.